# Question on the integral of the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(s)$

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, roots, riemann-zeta

Consider the function $f(x)$ defined in formula (1) below and the related function $F(s)$ defined in formula (2) below (which corresponds to the integral of the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(s)$).

---

**(1)** $\quad f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=2}^x\frac{1}{\log(n)}-\delta (x-1)$

**(2)** $\quad F(s)=\int \zeta(s)\,ds=-s\int\limits_0^\infty f(x)\ x^{-s-1}\,dx=s-\underset{N\to \infty }{\text{lim}}\ \sum\limits_{n=2}^N\frac{1}{\log(n)\,n^s}\,,\quad\Re(s)>1$

---

The following plot illustrates formula (2) for the function $F(s)=\int\zeta(s)\,ds$ evaluated at $N=1000$, $N=10000$, and $N=100000$ in blue, orange, and green respectively.

---

[image: Illustration of formula (2) for the function F(s)]

**Figure (1)**: Illustration of formula (2) for the function $F(s)=\int\zeta(s)\,ds$

---

Note $F(s)=\int\zeta(s)\,ds$ has a zero somewhere in the range $1<s<2$.

---

> **Question 1**: Is there a closed expression for the location of the zero of $F(s)=\int\zeta(s)\,ds$ in the range $1<s<2$?

---

Note formula (2) for $F(s)=\int\zeta(s)\,ds$ converges for $\Re(s)>1$.

---

> **Question (2)**: Does the function $F(s)=\int\zeta(s)\,ds$ have an analytic continuation for $\Re(s)\le 1$ and if so, what is known about the locations of the zeros of $F(s)=\int\zeta(s)\,ds$?

Comment: "$\int \zeta(s)$" is gibberish.  This lacks a differential.  Also,an antiderivative (general integral) is not a specific function, it is an infinite collection of functions (hence, the "${}+C$").  Your right-hand integral obscures which antiderivative you mean, which is critical, because different antiderivatives have the zero you ask about in different places.  (The "${}+C$" translates the graph up and down, shifting the zero left and right, respectively.)

Comment: The pole at $1$ implies that $F$ has a logarithmic singularity, so you need to cut there; if you take $(s-1)\zeta$ you are good

Comment: For the analytic continuation use that $\int_2^s (\zeta(z)-\frac1{z-1})dz$ is entire..

Comment: @EricTowers I added $ds$ to the integral of $\zeta(s)$ (i.e. $\int\zeta(s)\,ds$) which should at least partially address your concerns. I assumed the integration constant was zero. I'm not sure if this is correct but believe both of my questions can be addressed in the context of the definition of $F(s)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An analytic continuation of
$$F(s) = s-\sum_{n\ge 2} \frac{n^{-s}}{\log n}$$ is $$F(s) = F(2+i\Im(s))+\int_{2+i\Im(s)}^s \zeta(z)dz$$
Note that $F(s)-\log(s-1)$ is a primitive of the entire function $\zeta(s)-\frac1{s-1}$ so it is entire.

Then $F(2+i\Im(s))= i\Im(s)+O(1)$ and for $\Re(s)\ge 0, \zeta(z)=O(|\Im(z)|^{1/2+\epsilon})+\frac1{z-1}$, whence there is some $T$ such that $F(s)$ has no zeros for $\Re(s)\in [0,2], \Im(s)\ge T$.

$F(s)$ also has no zeros for $\Re(s)\ge 10$.

On a neighborhood of $s=1$ we have $F(s)=\log(s-1)+O(1)$ so it has no zeros as well.

The finitely many zeros on $\Re(s)\ge 0$ (finitely for the principal branch of $\log$) are found with the argument principle.

With the functional equation of $\zeta(s)$ we can probably say something about $\Re(s)\le 0$ as well.

Comment: Ok but it doesn't change anything